# Resolve: $4\sin(2x)+4\cos(x)-5=0$

Tags: trigonometry, cubics, quartics

The first thing that comes to mind is to substitute $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ and so we have:
\begin{align*}
8\sin(x)\cos(x)+4\cos(x)-5=0
\end{align*}
But after that I can't see what other identity to apply, I've been checking several times, if it is necessary to add something or multiply properly, but I can't find anything.

Comment: Based on your work so far, my first try, **which might very plausibly fail** would be to substitute $\pm \sqrt{1 - \cos^2(x)}$ for $\sin(x)$.  I would focus on splitting the analysis into two cases, depending on whether $\sin(x) \geq 0$ or $\sin(x) < 0.$  Then, in each case, I would have an equation in a single variable : $\cos(x)$.  Notice that the typical attack of an equation like $\sqrt{f(x)} + g(x) = h(x)$ is by $f(x) = [h(x) - g(x)]^2.$  Solving this gives **candidate** values for $f(x)$ that have to be manually checked against the original equation.

Comment: Roots of this equation are difficult to pronounce (Try [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4sin2x%2B4cosx-5%3D0)). But unless there is a typo, you get nice solutions to $4\sin^2x+4\cos x-5=0$.

Comment: Nothing nice seems to work here. If you square $4 \cos x (2 \sin x + 1) = 5$, and replace $\cos^2x$ with $1- \sin^2x$, then it comes down to solution to $64 y^4 + 64y^3 - 48 y^2 - 64 y + 9 = 0$... where $y = \sin x$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

By [tangent half angle identities](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula) we obtain

$$\frac{16t(1-t^2)}{(1+t^2)^2}+\frac{4(1-t^2)}{1+t^2}-5=0$$

$$\iff 9 t^4 + 16 t^3 + 10 t^2 - 16 t +1=0$$

which can be studied by [IVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) to show that two real solutions exist.

Answer (score 2):

I want to release the user's hint.

Let $\tan\frac{x}{2}=t$.

Thus, $$\sin\frac{x}{2}=\frac{2t}{1+t^2},$$
$$\cos\frac{x}{2}=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$

and we need to solve that
$$\frac{16t(1-t^2)}{(1+t^2)^2}+\frac{4(1-t^2)}{1+t^2}-5=0$$ or
$$9t^4+16t^3+10t^2-16t+1=0$$ or for any $\alpha$
$$(1-8t+\alpha t^2)^2-t^2((\alpha^2-9)t^2-16(\alpha+1)t+2a+54)=0.$$
Now, we'll choose a value of $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^2-9>0$, $\alpha+27>0$ and
$$64(\alpha+1)^2-(2\alpha+54)(\alpha^2-9)=0$$ or
$$\alpha^3-5\alpha^2-73\alpha-275=0,$$ which gives
$$\alpha=\frac{1}{3}\left(5+2\sqrt[3]{685-6\sqrt{6729}}+2\sqrt[3]{685+6\sqrt{6729}}\right)$$ and for this value of $\alpha$ we need to solve
$$(1-8t+\alpha t^2)^2-t^2\left(\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}t-\frac{8(\alpha+1)}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}}\right)^2=0$$ or
$$\left(\left(\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}-\alpha\right)t^2-8\left(\tfrac{\alpha+1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}}-1\right)t-1\right)\left(\left(\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}+\alpha\right)t^2-8\left(\tfrac{\alpha+1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}}+1\right)t+
1\right)=0.$$
Easy to see that the equation $$\left(\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}-\alpha\right)t^2-8\left(\tfrac{\alpha+1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}}-1\right)t-
1=0$$ has no real roots, but the second equation $$\left(\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}+\alpha\right)t^2-8\left(\tfrac{\alpha+1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}}+1\right)t+1=0$$ gives
$$t=\frac{4\left(\frac{\alpha+1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}}+1\right)+\sqrt{16\left(\frac{\alpha+1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}}+1\right)^2-\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}-\alpha}}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}+\alpha}$$ or
$$t=\frac{4\left(\frac{\alpha+1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}}+1\right)-\sqrt{16\left(\frac{\alpha+1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}}+1\right)^2-\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}-\alpha}}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}+\alpha},$$
which gives the answer:
$$x=2\arctan\frac{4\left(\frac{\alpha+1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}}+1\right)+\sqrt{16\left(\frac{\alpha+1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}}+1\right)^2-\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}-\alpha}}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}-\alpha}+2\pi k$$  or

$$x=2\arctan\frac{4\left(\frac{\alpha+1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}}+1\right)-\sqrt{16\left(\frac{\alpha+1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}}+1\right)^2-\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}-\alpha}}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-9}+\alpha}+2\pi k,$$ where $k$ is an integer number and $\alpha=\frac{1}{3}\left(5+2\sqrt[3]{685-6\sqrt{6729}}+2\sqrt[3]{685+6\sqrt{6729}}\right).$

Answer (score 2):

If you plot the function
$$f(x)=4\sin(2x)+4\cos(x)-5$$ by inspection or drawing, you will notice that, for $0 \leq x \leq 2\pi$, there are two roots; one of them is close to $0$ and the other one close to $\frac \pi 3$.

Using Taylor expansions, we have
$$f(x)=-1+8 x-2 x^2-\frac{16 x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{6}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ Using now series reversion
$$x=t+\frac{t^2}{4}+\frac{19 t^3}{24}+\frac{57 t^4}{64}+O\left(t^5\right)\qquad \text{with} \qquad t=\frac {1+f(x)}8$$ Making $f(x)=0$ as desired, an estimate is
$$x=\frac{102763}{786432}=0.130670$$ while the solution given by Newton method is $x=0.130753$.

Doing the same around $x=\frac \pi 3$
$$f(x)=\left(2 \sqrt{3}-3\right)-\left(4+2 \sqrt{3}\right) \left(x-\frac{\pi
   }{3}\right)-\left(1+4 \sqrt{3}\right) \left(x-\frac{\pi
   }{3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{8}{3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) \left(x-\frac{\pi
   }{3}\right)^3+\left(\frac{1}{12}+\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\right) \left(x-\frac{\pi
   }{3}\right)^4+O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{3}\right)^5\right)$$ Using again series reversion
$$x=\frac{\pi }{3}+t+\left(5-\frac{7 \sqrt{3}}{2}\right) t^2+\left(\frac{377}{3}-71
   \sqrt{3}\right) t^3+\left(3486-\frac{8069 \sqrt{3}}{4}\right)
   t^4+O\left(t^5\right)$$ where $t=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{3}-2\right) \left(f(x)-2 \sqrt{3}+3\right)$. This gives as an estimate
$$x=\frac{\pi }{3}+\frac{9}{64} \left(523823248-302429493 \sqrt{3}\right)=1.10580$$
while the solution given by Newton method is $x=1.10582$.